# How to call sequence of function?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, generics

Actually I need to know how this line is getting executed.

Example:

```
Browser("InternetExplorer").Page("Stackoverflow").WebElement("textbox").set "user"
```

The above lines executes like setting browser to Internet Explorer and finding page "stackoverflow" in it and then finding webelement "textbox" in it and then sets it values to "user". in this way the operation is done.

I want to know how this sequence call are be done. I don't want how browser is set to Internet Explorer and so on.

I need to execute a simple statement like

Fun("add").values("2,3").compute

I need the above line to execute by calling "add" function then values "2,3" are passed as parameter then "compute" add it and the final result should "5" be return.

How to do this? Whether we have to use different class for "Fun" and "values" or we need to implement them as "functions" of same class.

How to process sequence call ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to return a reference to an existing object to achieve this effect:

```
class Operator
{
public:
    Operator(const string& opAsStr)
    {
        ...
    }

    Operator& Values(const string& operands)
    {
        ....
        return *this;
    }

    int Compute() // Compute must be a function, no properties in C++
    {
        ...
    }
};

// Usable like this
Operator("Add").Values("2,3").Compute()
```

By defining more function returning `*this` you can chain many calls. Note that you could return a value (i.e. `Operator` instead of a reference, or a const reference depending on your use cases).
You can also return a reference (or value) to an object of another class:

```
class A
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        ....
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    A MakeA()
    {
         return A();
    }
};

B().MakeA().DoSomething();
```